# Should we downvote an old answer that did work at some point so that maybe the answer could be updated?

Tags: discussion, questions

I found a question about a problem that I was having while building an Android app. The question had lots of answers associated with it, yet none of the answers worked. They probably did work at some point, but the Android platform has transformed a lot over the years. My question is, should we downvote an old answer that did work at some point so that maybe the answer could be updated? In my case, I figured out the answer and added my answer to the question. The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376730/android-finish-activity-context/21586392#21586392)

Comment: Hard to see it, every answer says "use finish()".  If you actually meant to document that a cast is no longer necessary then be sure to state that explicitly.

Comment: Have you tried commenting first?

Comment: Actually, I would not normally comment. I would continue my search for the answer, but I will keep that in mind for future situations.

Comment: In that question, your case seems to be different from the OP. The OP had a reference to the Context in a class that is not an Activity and wanted to finish that activity. You seem to be calling that method from an Activity class... So the difference there is not due to the platform being updated. You and the OP have 2 different situations.

Comment: That could be the case. I am very new to `Android` and I was new to programming in general when I had this problem.

Comment: @TylerH the difficulty with "Have you tried commenting first?" is that not everyone can comment. (Eg. newbies) I've been on the site ~1 year, and only just recently got the privilege to comment everywhere.

Comment: @EdwinChua I was replying to Sedrick who has the ability to comment everywhere. It was a request for more info on what OP had already done; it wasn't general advice. But aside from that, a year is an abnormally long time to participate on a site without getting to 50 rep.

Comment: I didn't at the time.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You should be voting on whether or not a post *is* useful.  Not whether or not a post *used* to be useful.

Now whether or not  the age of the post has made it no longer useful is a question that you'll need to decide on yourself.  For many products there are lots of users still using older versions of a product, so the existence of an answer for that old version may well still be very useful, and at most you would only need to edit a post to make it clear what version(s) the answer applies to (because often people don't bother to say so when they're using the version that was current at the time of the post).

For other types of products certain types of old information may simply *have no use at all*.  For example information about a hosted app for which it's not *possible* to use older version even if you wanted to might be determined by subject matter experts to just not be useful to *anyone* anymore, if it's not even *possible* for it to apply to anyone.

Where feasible, and useful (which should *often* be the case) it's good enough to just edit an older post to indicate what version(s) it applies to, (or to make that information more prominent, if necessary).

Also note here that sometimes it's appropriate to edit the answer, but sometimes it's appropriate to edit *the question*.  If there's a problem that someone asked about that just doesn't even make sense to ask about after version X of a product, update *the question* to indicate that it's asking about how to do [this thing] before version X, rather than editing an answer to say "This is a good solution before version X".  For problems where the problem is the same regardless of version/age, but only the answers are different, then that's where you'd edit the answers, not the question.

But at the end of the day, if you can't edit the post into something that *is* useful, then your vote should most certainly reflect how useful it actually is.

Comment: Do you have boilerplate answers ready or so? In the time I manage to produce 2 mediocre comments, you post a full fledged answer ...

Comment: @rene Well I did edit some of this in.  Most of the second half of this answer was ninja edited in.  But no, I didn't write any of this before reading the question.

Comment: hat tip deserved ...

Comment: I like the point you made about `Versions`. Many Android phones do still run an old version of Android and people can still make apps catering to those phones. When I answer a question in the future, I am going to try to make a habit of putting version info in the answer. I answer some `Java` and `JavaFX` questions and with the new `Java9` some things are different  from the older still popular `Java8`.

Comment: You can hardly "bring to top" highly voted post which uses even, for example deprecated API. I bet many "gimme teh codez" programmers will use the "top voted one code" without reading the "whole thread" no matter what.

Comment: @Victoria If someone is blindly copying some code without even reading the answer that they're using then, frankly, they're going to have pretty major problems as a programmer, and there isn't much SO can do about that.  If they're not even willing to read a disclaimer at the start of the answer that it only applies to people using version X of a product, when they're using version X+10, the consequences are on them at that point, at least in my view.

Comment: @Servy, well, to be honest, I'm not the one who introduces answer with _"this applies since <version>"_ and with the new, modified version changes the answer by adding _"..until <version>"_. I have different things to do as well :) How can a newbie then distinguish between just outdated and wrong answer without having even possibility to see the score balance?

Comment: @Victoria That's fine, and of course for the vast majority of answers that type of information isn't necessary.  It's only really important *after* the solution in the answer is entirely obsolete and no longer usable in the current version.  Once that happens, the answer may cease to be useful if not edited to properly address that fact, and you may find that votes reflect that until the post is edited.

Comment: @Servy, if there was a _mechanism_ as used to be in documentation, I would use it (that frame with version looked good anyway). The rest would be categorising tags into versions. All that is not so diffictult.